# Issue with Joining multiple similar tables

Tags: sql, view, union, greatest-n-per-group

I have three table with the same column names: [PARTNO],[DATETIME], etc. and I have created a view to combine all three:

```
SELECT *
FROM         SPC.dbo.VDATA
UNION 
SELECT     *
FROM         SPC_Archive.dbo.VDATA
UNION 
SELECT     *
FROM         SPC.dbo.VDATA1
UNION 
SELECT     *
FROM         SPC_Archive.dbo.VDATA1
UNION     SELECT     *
FROM         SPC.dbo.VDATA2
UNION 
SELECT     *
FROM         SPC_Archive.dbo.VDATA2
```

The problem I am running into is that I need it to return only one value for the [PARTNO] and the [DATETIME] and I am not sure how to do that on a union....

Comment: Do you want only one row per `PARTNO`  or just a single row as result

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe you are trying to GROUP on PARTNO after performing the UNION.  You can use a nested query for this.  For example, if you are trying to find the maximum DATETIME per PARTNO across all the tables, you could:

```
SELECT PARTNO, MAX([DATETIME])
FROM (
    SELECT PARTNO, [DATETIME] FROM SPC.dbo.VDATA
    UNION SELECT PARTNO, [DATETIME] FROM SPC_Archive.dbo.VDATA
    UNION SELECT ...
    UNION SELECT ...
) combined 
GROUP BY combined.PARTNO
```